# I fail to understand MediaWiki HTMLForm manual

Tags: php, html, templates, mediawiki, contact-form

I want to change the default MediaWiki [ContactPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ContactPage) contact form so that my form **would not** contain:

- An inputtable heading
- An inputtable text area

Rather, I want it to contain just a simple select list and (the already existing) inputtable email field.

The select list should be of this pattern:

```
<select name="fruits">
    <option value ="none">Nothing</option>
    <option value ="guava">Guava</option>
    <option value ="lychee">Lychee</option>
    <option value ="papaya">Papaya</option>
</select>
```

Because in MediaWiki it is possible to customize the PHP of a ContactPage contact form by any of the HTMLForm (template engine) templates,
I tried to read [in HTMLForm manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HTMLForm) to understand what template to use for a select list;
I found the following template `omgaselectbox` as most suitable:

```
'omgaselectbox' => [
    'class' => 'HTMLSelectField',
    'label' => 'Select an oooption',
    'options' => [
        'Pirates' => 'pirate',
    'Ninjas' => 'ninja',
    'Back to the NINJAR!' => 'ninjars',
    ],
],
```

### My problem

I don't understand from both ContactForm and HTMLForm manuals what is `omgaselectbox` - if it's just a name or a command,
I further don't understand from these manuals if the final contact form code should be changed from including this:

```
'AdditionalFields' => array(
    'Text' => array(
        'label-message' => 'emailmessage',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'rows' => 20,
            'required' => true,  // Either "true" or "false" as required
    ),
    'omgaselectbox' => [
        'class' => 'HTMLSelectField',
        'label' => 'Select an oooption',
        'options' => [
            'Pirates' => 'pirate',
        'Ninjas' => 'ninja',
        'Back to the NINJAR!' => 'ninjars',
        ],
    ],
),
```

to including only this:

```
'AdditionalFields' => array(
    'omgaselectbox' => [
        'class' => 'HTMLSelectField',
        'label' => 'Select an oooption',
        'options' => [
            'Pirates' => 'pirate',
        'Ninjas' => 'ninja',
        'Back to the NINJAR!' => 'ninjars',
        ],
    ],
),
```

### My question

What is the meaning of `omgaselectbox` and what was I correct about the final contact form code?

Comment: @04FS Indeed I referred to that manual; I didn't speak about `myfield1` or `myfield2`; I didn't check tutorial 2 because I didn't understand tutorial 1 and checking tutorial 2 is something I personally wouldn't have done because I would assume I should go "step by step" → I think all of what I misunderstood should have been explained by comment under the relevant example in tutorial 1.

Comment: I thank you and tgr for gracefully helping me understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array key is the field name (ie. the `name` property of the resulting `<input>` or `<select>`; also the array key in the array of values returned by HTMLForm after processing and validating the form submit). Presumably it stands for "[OMG](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/omg) a select box!"

You can remove the `Text` field but then there won't be a way for the user to write a message, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Hello Tgr; I tried to edit your answer in a way I found significantly making it easier to read and process (think) and also more well adjusted to the order of the two sub-questions.

Comment: Sadly, two mods rejected the edit, but you have the power to approve it anyway on top of the mods if you recognize this is a correct step.

Comment: Please go through my edit and contemplate this and if you finally choose not to approve it, please feel welcome to flags these comments.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your help and time,

Answer (score 0):

<sub>The following "answer" is only a rewriting of the answer by `user:Tgr` which I accepted;

I rewrote it in a way I find more ordinal and clear; in my opinion it shouldn't be up voted or downvoted.
 I am sorry if I was wrong in anything - please comment about such error.</sub>

---

Presumably, `omg` in `omgaselectbox` stands for "[OMG](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/omg), a select box!"

The array key is the field name (ie. the `name` property of the resulting `<input>` or `<select>`; also the array key in the array of values returned by HTMLForm after processing and validating the form submit). Presumably it stands for "[OMG](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/omg) a select box!"
The array key is the field name (ie. the `name` property of the resulting `<input>` or `<select>`;
also, it is the array key returned with the array of values by HTMLForm after processing the form submit.

That said,
You can remove the `Text` field but then there won't be a way for the user to write a message, which is probably not what you want.